# Retrieve process information and files from a remoted machine

Tags: c#, remote-access

I’m trying to retrieve a specific process using the following code:

```
Process[] Process = Process.GetProcessesByName(_ProcessName, _Ip);
```

When `_Ip` is “127.0.0.1”, the process is retrieved successfully.
When `_Ip` represents a remote machine, the following exception occurs:

```
System.InvalidOperationException occurred
  HResult=-2146233079
  Message=Couldn't connect to remote machine.
  Source=System
  StackTrace:
       at System.Diagnostics.NtProcessManager.GetProcessInfos(String machineName, Boolean isRemoteMachine)
       at System.Diagnostics.ProcessManager.GetProcessInfos(String machineName)
       at System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcesses(String machineName)
       at System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName(String processName, String machineName)
       at ToisSimulator.ToisResultsCollector.CollectResults() in d:\PI2\ThirdParty\TCC_New\TccMediator\ToisSimulator\ToisResultsCollector.cs:line 101
  InnerException: System.InvalidOperationException
       HResult=-2146233079
       Message=Couldn't get process information from performance counter.
       Source=System
       StackTrace:
            at System.Diagnostics.NtProcessManager.GetProcessInfos(PerformanceCounterLib library)
            at System.Diagnostics.NtProcessManager.GetProcessInfos(String machineName, Boolean isRemoteMachine)
       InnerException: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception
            HResult=-2147467259
            Message=Access is denied
            Source=System
            ErrorCode=-2147467259
            NativeErrorCode=5
            StackTrace:
                 at System.Diagnostics.PerformanceMonitor.Init()
                 at System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounterLib.GetPerformanceData(String item)
                 at System.Diagnostics.NtProcessManager.GetProcessInfos(PerformanceCounterLib library)
            InnerException:
```

I tried to do the following:

1. Ping between the two machine – succeeded
2. Cancel the FireWall at the remote machine
3. Enable and start the “Remote Registry” service on both machines

The purpose of retrieving the process is to find it’s directory path and read log files that are located in that directory using the following code line:

```
FileStream fStream = new FileStream(fileInfo.FullName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite);
```

Answer (score 2):

Hope you have tried [Process Information on Remote Computer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6476143/process-information-on-remote-computer)
.
It says right way is to have `WMI`.

This link has nice example for this, this uses `System.Management` to connect to remote system and get process details.